# ManyToOne Doctrine Database Relation with Extra Field Symfony 3

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm just new in Symfony so please bear with me.

I want to create a database relationship in Symfony, let say..

I have Entity `Currency`, `AddRate` and `AddRateCurrency` 
These entities would accomplish 3 simple things.

1. The User will gonna add different types of currencies using `Currency` entity.
2. The User will gonna choose which branch these currencies must be added using `AddRate` entity.
3. The User will gonna update the rates of each currency using `AddRateCurrency`.

The problem that I encountered is

> Expected value of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|array"
>   for association field "MontealBundle\Entity\AddRate#$currency", got
>   "MontealBundle\Entity\Currency" instead.

On adding rate `AddRateForm` I used `EntityType` to embed my form.

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('branch', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Branch',
                'class'=>'MontealBundle\Entity\Branch',
                'query_builder' => function (BranchRepository $er) {
                    return $er->findAllActiveBranches();
                },
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'placeholder' => 'Choose a Branch',
                'empty_data' => null,
                'required' => true,
                'constraints' => array(
                    new NotBlank(array("message" => 'Branch is required.'))
                )
            ))
            ->add('currency', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Currency',
                'class'=>'MontealBundle\Entity\Currency',
                'query_builder' => function (CurrencyRepository $er) {
                    return $er->findAllActiveCurrencies();
                },
                'choice_label' => 'currency',
                'placeholder' => 'Choose a Currency',
                'empty_data' => null,
                'multiple' => true,
                // 'expanded' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'constraints' => array(
                    new NotBlank(array("message" => 'Currency is required.'))
                )
            ))
        ;
    }
```

On `Currency` Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="currency")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MontealBundle\Repository\CurrencyRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"code"}, message="Code is already used.")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"currency"}, message="Currency is already used.")
 */
class Currency
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Administrator")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="administrator_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $administrator;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
     */
    private $currency;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAdministrator()
    {
        return $this->administrator;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $administrator
     */
    public function setAdministrator($administrator)
    {
        $this->administrator = $administrator;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCurrency()
    {
        return $this->currency;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $currency
     */
    public function setCurrency($currency)
    {
        $this->currency = $currency;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $code
     */
    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $status
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function setCreatedAt()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt()
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
    }
}
```

On `AddRate` Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="add_rate")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MontealBundle\Repository\AddRateRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class AddRate
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Branch")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="branch_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $branch;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AddRateCurrency", mappedBy="add_rate")
     */
    private $currency;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->currency = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Administrator")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="administrator_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $administrator;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBranch()
    {
        return $this->branch;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $branch
     */
    public function setBranch($branch)
    {
        $this->branch = $branch;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCurrency()
    {
        return $this->currency;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $currency
     */
    public function setCurrency($currency)
    {
        $this->currency = $currency;
    }

    public function addCurrency(Currency $currency) {
        $this->currency[] = $currency;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAdministrator()
    {
        return $this->administrator;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $administrator
     */
    public function setAdministrator($administrator)
    {
        $this->administrator = $administrator;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function setCreatedAt()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }
}
```

On `AddRateCurrency` Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="add_rate_currency")
 */
class AddRateCurrency
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AddRate", inversedBy="AddRateCurrency")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $currency;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $rate;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCurrency()
    {
        return $this->currency;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $currency
     */
    public function setCurrency($currency)
    {
        $this->currency = $currency;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getRate()
    {
        return $this->rate;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $rate
     */
    public function setRate($rate)
    {
        $this->rate = $rate;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `AddRate` entity, remove the `setCurrency` function. Symfony will then (automatically) use your `addCurrency` function instead since `$currency` is an ArrayCollection.

Your choice of variable names adds to the confusion somewhat. In `AddRate`, you may want to consider renaming `$currency` to `$currencies`.